# Celestia for Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, software-center, software-sources

A number of years back, while on Linux Mint 11, in the Software Store(not the actual name but you get the idea) I happened across Celestia, a fun little Astronomy program.  It seems as though it has been wiped out since then.  Is there somewhere I can get this program for installation in Ubuntu 18.04?  I really enjoyed this program, and would like to have it again.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: Apparently not: https://celestia.space/download.html.

Comment: Celestia isn't in the 18.04 repos.

Comment: I found it but the file extension is .package.  It has no autoinstall and I have no idea how to proceed from there

Answer (score 1):

The `celestia` package was [removed](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/celestia) from Ubuntu before 16.04 due to lack of interest by the community. The previous community volunteers who had packaged the software from [upstream](https://celestia.space/) found new interests, and no community volunteer has stepped to resume packaging in either deb or [snap](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-wishlist-suggestions-wanted/567/111) format.

Anybody willing to put in a small amount of effort can do the [deb](https://mentors.debian.net/) or [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) packaging. You don't need to be a developer - you simply need to be willing to learn the process.

In the meantime, here is [one way to build Celestia](https://celestia.space/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=18430&p=141157&hilit=ubuntu#p141157). Since it's not packaged for Ubuntu, installation questions or problems are likely to get faster answers if directed to the Celestia support forum.

Alternately, there are several other overlapping applications like Stellarium and Kstars which are packaged for Ubuntu and are in the Software Center.

Comment: Can you point me to any tutorials?  I found it as a .package file but then I'm stuck again.  I pretty much a noob at this stuff.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to request installation instructions for third party software here, even when there is a support forum...

Comment: Of course, you aren't obliged to provide them in your answer here :)